# Java - How to return term as a polynomial

Tags: java, while-loop, return, polynomials

I have an array storing the `coefficient` and `exponent` of each term of a polynomial, type `Term(coefficient, exponent)`. I need to return the polynomial as a string for display with each term in the form "`coefficient*x^exponent`".

Here's what I have so far.

```
    public Polynomial solveSequence()
    {
        int exponent;
        int i = 0;
        Term[] poly = new Term[i];
        while (exponent > 0)
        {
            poly[i] = nextTerm();
            updateSequence(nextTerm());
            getSequence();
            i++;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a separate `Polynomial` class?  Do you want this function to return a `Polynomial` or a `String`?  Also, you're creating your `Term` array with a size of zero.

Comment: I want to return the polynomial as a string. Currently I get the error "incompatible types: Term[] cannot be converted to Polynomial"

Comment: Can you post your `nextTerm()`, `updateSequence()`, and `getSequence()` methods?

Comment: Why is your Term array initialized with a zero?

Comment: My mistake initializing with a zero.

nextTerm() creates the next term of my polynomial from a sequence I have been given.
updateSequence() and getSequence() get the next sequence from which I get the next term.

Comment: How does your Term class look like? Which methods does it have?

Comment: This isn't clear; where are you stuck?